# Connecting VPN using Rasphone and | | command in a Batch File

Tags: batch-file, cmd, vpn

this in my batch file command:

```
@echo off
rasphone -d a -f e:\vpn.pbk >nul || (
rasphone -d b -f e:\vpn.pbk
)
exit 0
```

I wanna connect to vpn "a" and if it fails try next one ( vpn "b") but when vpn "a" facing an error the command stops until I close the error window!
I'm using Windows 7 x86 SP1 and I have unchecked "Display progress while connecting " & " Prompt for name and password..." and changed the redial attempts to 0 in my vpn properties and the address of PBK file is correct...
How can I fix this problem ?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: why don't you try with RASDIAL? Since RASDIAL doesn't support user interface, all the errors will be shown in the console instead of a error window. RASDIAL documentation: https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/rasdial.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: RASDIAL give me this error in Windows 7: Remote Access error 691 - The remote connection was denied because the user name
 and password combination you provided is not recognized, or the selected authentication protocol is not permitted on the remote access server.___________________ but the username and password is correct!

Comment: you might be using Secure Socket Tunneling Protocol(SSTP) for connecting to VPN. This is not supported by RASDIAL.

Comment: no, I'm using PPTP for VPN and the encryption for the connection is off.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
rasphone -d a -f e:\vpn.pbk >nul && exit
rasphone -d b -f e:\vpn.pbk
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but this is still not working for me . It stops when the Redial box appears :(

Answer (score 0):

You may connect to preconfigured VPN in windows by this command :

```
rasdial.exe VpnConnectionName Username Password
```